# Node.js Puppeteer - Navigation timeout error

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to grab data off a web page. I had this running on my Windows environment but when I switched over to Ubuntu 18.04, it throws a navigation timeout error. I've tried to disable timeout errors with no luck. I'm using `const fs = require('fs');` so I can bypass Chegg's captcha  for bots.

```
async function login_chegg() {

global.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox'],
    headless: true,
    slowMo: 100,
    userDataDir: 'userdata/chromium',
});

global.page = await browser.pages();
var userAgent = require('user-agents');

await page[0].setUserAgent(userAgent.toString());
console.log("Going to Chegg");
await page[0].goto("https://www.chegg.com/auth?action=login&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chegg.com%2F", {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
});
```

This is the error I get.

> Going to Chegg (node:4328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
> TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded     at
> /root/chegg-bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:106:111
> at emitUnhandledRejectionWarning
> (internal/process/promises.js:168:15)     at processPromiseRejections
> (internal/process/promises.js:247:11)     at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:32) (node:4328) TimeoutError:
> Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded   at
> /root/chegg-bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:106:111
> (node:4328) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
> are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
> will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.     at
> emitDeprecationWarning (internal/process/promises.js:180:11)  at
> processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:249:13)    at
> processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:32)

Comment: Did you try to increase the default time out of 30sec? You do slow motion and probably require more time to load the page, so try to add `timeout` to [goto](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.2.1/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) according to doc.

Comment: Yes. I've added `timeout` both to something like 1m and 0 to disable it timing out. I still have the same issue.